# Raspberry Pi 3B+ Bluetooth undiscoverable on iPhone

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, pi-3b+

I installed latest version of Raspbian Stretch with desktop (which comes with pre installed bluetooth). I turned the bluetooth on, and made it discoverable. At the same time I searched for available devices on my Android and iPhone phones.

The Android phone could see raspberrypi in Available Devices list, but the iPhone didn't discover it.

What could be the issue for iPhone?

Comment: This is a problem of the IPhone and not of the Raspberry Pi, isn't it?

Comment: Try disabling and re-enabling Bluetooth from the Settings menu in iOS. Also forget any devices that exist there, just in case. Finally, make sure that the Raspberry Pi is close by just in case this is an antenna issue.

Comment: @Ingo Unless the iPhone fails to connect to any BT device, I'd say it's an iPhone/RPi interoperability problem, so it's not automatically off-topic.